# How can I add html elements to the current page? puppeter/carlo

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to add html elements to the current page from

```
page.setContenet
```

but when it reaches:

```
await page.setContent('<div><h1>hello world<h1></div>')
```

Refresh the page and say goodbye to `./index.html`

Is there a way that these 2 functions work in the same window at the same time?

full code:

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path');
const carlo = require('carlo');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const { getExecutablePath } = require('./utils');

const run = async () => {
  const executablePath = await getExecutablePath({
  //  useLocalChromium: true
  });
  console.log('Executable path:', executablePath);
  launchPuppeteer({ executablePath });
}

run();

const launchPuppeteer = async launchOptions => {
  const test = path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  const final = test + '/index.html';
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [`--app=${final}`, '--window-size=1280,1024'],
    ...launchOptions
  });

  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 1024});
  await page.setContent('<div><h1>hello world<h1></div>')
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify, what "these 2 functions"? What does this mean? - "Refresh the page and say goodbye"

Comment: You have missed the `await` before the `launchPuppeteer` function. `await launchPuppeteer({ executablePath })`

Comment: @Vaviloff an apology. What I am trying to do is add html tags to my index.html.

I use `await page.setContent ('<div> <h1> hello world <h1> </div>')`

but when but when this part of the code arrives, it updates the browser and my index.html disappears.

Comment: @Yevhen done but it seems that it continues doing what I describe above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this

```
await page.evaluate(()=>{
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div>Test</div>';
})
```

Edit: what about this?

Comment: I have the following `(node:6496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: main is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, you should put 'main' instead of main

Comment: `(node:6248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` I guess this happens because I don't have a selector with this name ... will it be correct?